# How to connect two tables with comma seperated values in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, join, subquery

I have below structured table.

```
ID QUESTION user_IDS
1   xyz ?    1,2,3
2   abc ?    4,5
```

Here , i want to take name of user's instead of ids from users table. I am using postgresql as database.

Desired out put should be

```
ID QUESTION users( from user table)
1   xyz?    mr.a, mr.b, mr.c
2   abc ?   mr.u, mr.y
```

Any kind of help will be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: please DDL of all related structure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can convert the comma separated list into an array and then use that in a join condition:

```
select q.id, q.question, string_agg(u.name, ',') as users
from questions q
  join users u on u.id = any(string_to_array(user_ids,',')::int[])
group by q.id;
```

Online example: http://rextester.com/ZWU18098